# How do I get JavaScript to load different sections of JSON data upon clicks on a nav bar

Tags: javascript, json, function

I am trying to create a program where you can click on a nav bar and it takes your to different pages with different content depending on what button the user clicks. For example if I pressed on books it would only load info about books and if I clicked games it would only load info about games.

Here is what the page should look like.

Here is my code.

```
function displayBooks () {
            let html = '<span> Filter: </span>';
            
            categories.forEach(category => {
                let htmlPlaceholder = `<label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="category" onclick="displayBooksItems(${category.id});"> 
                    ${category.name} </label>`;
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('nav');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        
        

        function displayBooksItems() {
        
            
            let html = '';
            items.forEach(item => {

            
                let htmlPlaceholder = 
                `<label> 
                    
                    ${item.categoryId}</label>`;
                
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('table');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 

        displayBooks ();

        function displayMusic () {
            let html = '<span> Filter: </span>';
            
            categories.forEach(category => {
                let htmlPlaceholder = `<label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="category" onclick="displayMusicItems(${category.id});"> 
                    ${category.name} </label>`;
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('nav');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        
        

        function displayMusicItems() {
        
            
            let html = '';
            items.forEach(item => {

            
                let htmlPlaceholder = 
                `<label> 
                    
                    ${item.image}</label>`;
                
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('table');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 

        displayMusic ();

        function displayGames () {
            let html = '<span> Filter: </span>';
            
            categories.forEach(category => {
                let htmlPlaceholder = `<label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="category" onclick="displayGamesItems(${category.id});"> 
                    ${category.name} </label>`;
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('nav');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        
        

        function displayGamesItems() {
        
            
            let html = '';
            items.forEach(item => {

            
                let htmlPlaceholder = 
                `<label> 
                    
                    ${item.price}</label>`;
                
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('table');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 

        displayGames ();
        
        function displayShoes () {
            let html = '<span> Filter: </span>';
            
            categories.forEach(category => {
                let htmlPlaceholder = `<label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="category" onclick="displayShoesItems(${category.id});"> 
                    ${category.name} </label>`;
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('nav');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        
        

        function displayShoesItems() {
        
            
            let html = '';
            items.forEach(item => {

            
                let htmlPlaceholder = 
                `<label> 
                
                    ${item.itemBrief}</label>`;
                
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('table');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        displayShoes ();

        function displayFurniture () {
            let html = '<span> Filter: </span>';
            
            categories.forEach(category => {
                let htmlPlaceholder = `<label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="category" onclick="displayFurnitureItems(${category.id});"> 
                    ${category.name} </label>`;
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('nav');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
        } 
        
        

        function displayFurnitureItems() {
        
            
            let html = '';
            items.forEach(item => {

            
                let htmlPlaceholder = 
                `<label> 
                    ${item.itemName}</label>`;
                
                html += htmlPlaceholder;
            });
            let categoryContainer = document.querySelector('table');
            categoryContainer.innerHTML = html;
            
        }
        displayFurniture ();
```

Comment: You can use `fetch` to load JSON. You can’t load only one part of the JSON unless you create several JSON files.

Comment: call the functions with a json object argument, so then you can use that specific part of your json object for the right function. like @Kokodoko said you can use fetch or other methods to get the json data and from there you can pass it to the correct functions.